# Find all-NaN columns in a martix

Tags: matlab, nan

I have an `m x n` matrix. I would like to get a logical `1 x n` vector where 'True' in the 4'th element indicates that the 4'th column was all `NaN` elements. What is the fastest way to accomplish that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do
`nancols = all(isnan(A), 1)`